# C++: What happens to a dynamically allocated object created as an argument in a constructor call?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

Say I am making a new object of class Foo, which takes an object of class Bar as a constructor argument. If I created this object in this manner:

```
Foo myObj(new Bar());
```

what happens in this case to the new object? I've seen code similar to this example (with no name for the new object created as an argument). Where would I put my `delete` call to free the memory taken by the Bar object?

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't have to write code like that. Either you have an owning raw pointer (which is bad) or you have a memory leak (which is worse). If you want `Foo` to take ownership of a pointer to `Bar` prefer to pass a `unique_ptr<Bar>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends, if it is allocated like in your example, hopefully your `Foo` class is managing it, otherwise the `Bar` will be leaked

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar* bar) : m_bar{bar} {}
    ~Foo() { delete m_bar; }
private:
    Bar* m_bar;
};
```

Or if you have access to C++11 you could have a `std::unique_ptr`

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar* bar) : m_bar{bar} {}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
};
```

Comment: In my opinion it would be preferable if the `unique_ptr` was passed into the constructor of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

`new Bar()` yields a pointer which becomes the constructor argument of `Foo(Bar*)` (or, if `Bar` is a class derived from `Base` the constructor may be `Foo(Base*`).

The corresponding constructor of `Foo` should deal with the resource as it is otherwise leaked.

Answer (score 0):

**It stays in the program.** If you have too many of these loose ends or if its repeated too often, the program will become a memory hog because it never returns the memory it borrows.

Yes, this is dangerous for loose ends. This is why people tend to use primitives like `std::unique_ptr<Type>` that manage themselves and automatically destruct as it goes out of scope and can also transfer ownership in natural ways.

Programming in that `delete myObj;` is often forgotten, so people have devised ways to get around it.

**If you have a manual `new` in a constructor, put the `delete` in the destructor. This concept is related to RAII: Resource Acquisition Is Initialization**